# What is the size of the icons in the system tray?

Tags: wpf, size, notifyicon

I want to change the notification icon of my application but don't know what is the size so as to make it  properly displayed. Currently it is automatically resized and break my pixels!
Please help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's 16x16. If you create a .ico file that supports 16, 32, 48 and 256 sizes, you're covered.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this?

Comment: basically you create a .ico at 256x256 and it will be scale down automatically by the OS

Comment: icon sushi is a free tool to create .ico files from appropriate pngs. Add them in order of size, 256, 48, 32, 16.

Answer (score 13):

In fact the size of the icon will vary according to the system DPI.

WPF exposes the recommended pixel width and height of small icons with [SystemParameters.SmallIconWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.smalliconwidth.aspx) and [SystemParameters.SmallIconHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.smalliconheight.aspx). (WinForms exposes the equivalent [SystemInformation.SmallIconSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.smalliconsize.aspx) - both just wrap around [GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) and SM_CXSMICON/SM_CYSMICON.)

[Microsoft recommends including 16x16 and 32x32 pixel icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330740(v=vs.85).aspx#install_icon).

Comment: Good info. I made a hand-drawn 16x16 icon, with "sharp" edges (no aliasing) and it doesn't really look right in my system tray. It's just barely shrinking it, probably by 2 to 4 pixels. Not sure there's any solving this, except to add some aliasing.

Comment: After changing dpi I still get the same (16). [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68352927/systemparameters-smalliconwidth-returns-16-on-any-dpi-so-how-can-i-check-for-ac).

Answer (score 3):

For XP it's 16 x 16

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu (unity) it seems to be 24x24 px.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 has 16*16 pixels icons in system tray.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook has an 16*16 pixels icon.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has always been 16x16, but at some point between 98 and XP (Maybe it was CE vs NT?) they learned to support full color and alpha transparency.  If you can, try to include a 256 color palleted version in the ICO for safe mode if not older versions of Windows.