# How many pixels in the Windows Taskbar Icons?

Tags: windows, icons, taskbar

I'm making a program that will show you when caps lock is turned on. I want it to display a little icon on the Windows Taskbar by the icons such as the battery, volume and internet connection. I was just wondering what the dimensions of the image could/should be.

Comment: This entirely depends on the screen resolution.  Why don't you just write the program to generate an taskbar icon itself?  Much easier then trying to hack a solution together.

Comment: @Ramhound, Will do. I think I could whip something up for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling on this...

```
windows tray icons resolution
```

... the first few hits are quite helpful; [What is the size of the icons in the system tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531232/what-is-the-size-of-the-icons-in-the-system-tray) says that

> It's 16x16. If you create a .ico file that supports 16, 32, 48 and 256 sizes, you're covered.

And it points [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#install_icon), where Microsoft recommends:

> Notification area icons should be high-DPI aware. An application should provide both a 16x16 pixel icon and a 32x32 icon in its resource file, and then use LoadIconMetric to ensure that the correct icon is loaded and scaled appropriately.