# SystemParameters.SmallIconWidth returns 16 on any dpi, so how can I check for actual best icon size?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I thought [SystemParameters.SmallIconWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.smalliconwidth) would tell me what's the best size icon for a small icon. However, even when I change the dpi in Settings->Display to 150% the value of `SystemParameters.SmallIconWidth` remains the same.

Is there a way to check for the best icon size?

(Why I thought that it should change by dpi - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4612308/939213), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8100520/939213) by a user with more than 500k rep.)

Comment: Are you sure your DPI changes took effect in your app? You restarted it?

Comment: @PmDuda Yes. I even cleaned the solution and rebuilt to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you declare full DPI awareness in the application manifest and/or at run-time, some Windows functions return 96 DPI (or System DPI) values for some reason. You have to pinvoke the new API:

```
public enum SystemMetric:int { SM_CXSMICON = 49 }
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SystemMetric smIndex, uint dpi);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetDpiForWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

HwndSource source = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(this);
IntPtr hWnd = source.Handle;
uint dpi = GetDpiForWindow(hWnd);
int width = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CXSMICON, dpi);
```

These functions only exist on Windows 10 update 1607 and later. If you need to support older versions you must manually scale the incorrect DPI value yourself (`x = x * dpi / 96`) instead of calling these functions.

See also:

- [Developing a Per-Monitor DPI-Aware WPF Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/declaring-managed-apps-dpi-aware)